# как распарсить JSON в swift

Tags: json, xcode, swift

не могу распасить вот это

```
{
    data =     {
        id = "kUu6AXbbN2tEeCJJ22fdHhB8R+viCPzuWrG7wDYpyY9K+2zqj5iJSUm09tDqow78L6yr2U8KObzW5VFtpeblzA==";
        logo = "http://www.example.com/images/logos/roboto.png";
        name = Ralf;
    };
    status = OK;
}
```

сам JSON приходит а вот что дальше

```
    if let myData = data{
    do{
    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: 
JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject}
                    catch{    
                    }
```

Comment: Очень рекомендую для парсинга JSON пользоваться [SwiftyJSON](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON) Там по ссылке есть примеры как это выглядит - намного удобнее и быстрее если много работаешь с JSON-ом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
}

            if let myData = data{
                do{
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let data = myJson["data"] as AnyObject? {
                        if let id = data["id"] as! NSString? {
                            print (id)
                        }
                        if let logo = data["logo"] as! NSString? {
                            print (logo)
                        }
                        if let name = data["name"] as! NSString? {
                            print (name)
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch{

                }
                }
```